# Korrekte Schreibweise von »100% Sicherheit«

Tags: spelling, numbers

Welche der folgenden Schreibweisen ist korrekt?

1. > Es besteht keine **100-prozentige** Sicherheit.
2. > Es besteht keine **100%ige** Sicherheit.
3. > Es besteht keine **100%** Sicherheit.

Comment: Das Wort "hundertprozentig" in Buchstaben auszuschreiben ist nicht erwünscht?

Comment: Martin, ich dachte (wahrscheinlich fälschlicherweise), dass Zahlen in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten bis zwölf ausgeschrieben werden... :S

Comment: @Serena: [So einfach ist das nicht.](//german.stackexchange.com/q/6748/2594) Gerade hier haben wir es nicht mit einer Zahl zu tun, deren exakter Wert irgendwie bestimmt wurde oder irgendwas vermittelt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Rechtschreibung

Zunächst einmal machen die Rechtschreibregeln keine Vorgaben, wann Ziffern und das Prozentzeichen auszuschreiben sind. Geregelt ist hingegen, wann ein Bindestrich oder Leerzeichen zu setzen ist. Hier können wir jetzt Fall für Fall durchgehen:

#### Alles ausgeschrieben

Hier greift zunächst § 36 (1.2):

> Substantive, Adjektive, Verben, Adverbien oder Wörter anderer Kategorien können als erster Bestandteil zusammen mit einem adjektivischen oder adjektivisch gebrauchten zweiten Bestandteil Zusammensetzungen bilden.
>
> Es wird zusammengeschrieben, wenn […] der […] zweite Bestandteil in dieser Form nicht selbständig vorkommt, zum Beispiel: *[…] letztmalig, […] blauäugig, großspurig, kleinmütig, vieldeutig; […]*

Da es kein Wort *prozentig* gibt, wird ***hundertprozentig*** zusammengeschrieben. Es greift keine der Regelungen, die hier einen Bindestrich zulassen könnten (§ 40, $ 42 – § 45).

#### Nur *Prozent* ausgeschrieben

An der Zusammenschreibung ändert sich nichts, § 40 (3) erzwingt jedoch einen Bindestrich:

> Man setzt einen Bindestrich in Zusammensetzungen mit Einzelbuchstaben, Abkürzungen oder Ziffern.
>
> Dies betrifft […] Zusammensetzungen mit Ziffern, zum Beispiel:
>   *[…], **100-prozentig**, […]*

#### Nichts ausgeschrieben

Hier greift nun § 41 als Ausnahme zu § 40:

> Vor Suffixen setzt man nur dann einen Bindestrich, wenn sie mit
>   einem Einzelbuchstaben verbunden werden.
>
> Beispiele:
>   *der x-te, zum x-ten Mal, die n-te Potenz*
>   E: Aber: *abclich, ÖVPler; der 68er, ein 32stel, **100%ig***

#### Gar kein *ig*

Kann man machen, dann wird aber auch kein *ig* gesprochen und die wir haben ein zusammengesetztes Substantiv à la *Fünfprozentklausel.*
Dann erzwingt zunächst § 37 die Zusammenschreibung *(Hundertprozentsicherheit):*

> Substantive, […] können mit Substantiven Zusammensetzungen bilden. Man schreibt sie ebenso wie mehrteilige Substantivierungen zusammen.

Will man abkürzen, greift dann wieder § 40 und man muss ***100%-Sicherheit*** bzw. ***100-Prozent-Sicherheit*** (zweiter Bindestrich nach § 44) schreiben.

## Stil

Anders als beim *42,5%igen Schnaps* oder bei der *12%igen Steigung* geht es bei der *hundertprozentigen Sicherheit* im gegebenen Kontext nicht darum, irgendeine gemessene oder anderweitig bestimmte Zahl zu kommunizieren.
Gerade in wissenschaftlichen Texten impliziert *100 %,* dass der wirkliche Wert zwischen 99.5 % und 100.5 % liegt (wobei letzteres im gegebenen Kontext natürlich keinen Sinn ergibt), was die gewünschte Aussage komplett zerstört.
Stattdessen wird *hundertprozentig* als fester Ausdruck genutzt, der hier äquivalent zu *völlig* ist.
Deswegen würde ich empfehlen es auszuschreiben, oder – um Verwirrungen mit hundertprozentiger Sicherheit zu vermeiden – durch ein völlig anderes Wort zu ersetzen, z. B. *völlig.*

Comment: a) Im Deutschen wird als Dezimaltrenner ausschließlich das Komma verwendet. b) Ohne den Kontext zu kennen ist die Behauptung, 99,5% sei der wirkliche Wert vermessen. c) Zwar ist es möglich auf einen anderen Begriff wie "völlig" auszuweichen - das beantwortet aber keine der Fragen und ist ein völlig subjektiver Vorschlag. Da 100%ig ebensogut ist, ist die Empfehlung fehl am Platze.

Comment: Die Antwort ist sehr gut und deckt alle möglichen Varianten ab. Deinen letzten Absatz halte ich aber schon für ein bißchen gewagt, da wir keinerlei Kontext kennen. Ohne Kontext halte ich *alle* Varianten für gleichberechtigt - Sonst gäbe es sie nicht.

Comment: @tofro: *da wir keinerlei Kontext kennen* – Doch, wir kennen einen Kontext; er wird in der Frage gegeben: »Es besteht keine 100%ige Sicherheit.« Wer dies sagt bzw. schreibt, muss damit rechnen, dass *100%ig* als *völlig* verstanden wird und der Satz als äquivalent zu: »Ein Restrisiko existiert.« Das ist etwas anderes als die *100%ige Steigung,* die sich nicht großartig von der *99%igen Steigung* und der *101%igen Steigung* unterscheidet.